# Azure ServiceBus from Xamarin Forms PCL

Tags: xamarin.forms, azureservicebus

How is brokered messaging via Azure Service Bus done from a Xamarin Forms PCL...is there an SDK, library or plugin? If there is a way to hand roll a brokered message, I suppose it could be accomplished with an HttpClient & the REST API ...

Comment: Are you targeting Windows, Android ans iOS ?

Comment: Only targeting iOS and Android for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally have a working method for posting a message to an Azure Service Bus Queue from a Xamarin PCL! The way to do this is via an HttpClient.

Gotchas that made the solution elusive:

- The nuget package for Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging will happily install, but has no exposure to the portable class.
- WebClient examples abound, but there is no webclient available in the
  PCL!
- PCL has no native crypto for HMACSHA256 for Shared Access Signature
  tokens.  Get the PCLCrypto package from nuget.
- Some documentation says request headers of Content-Type : application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8, and BrokerProerties are required. Ain't so!
- The path to post to is: BaseServiceBusAddress + queue + "/messages"

  ```
  public const string ServiceBusNamespace = [YOUR SERVICEBUS NAMESPACE];

  public const string BaseServiceBusAddress = "https://" + ServiceBusNamespace + ".servicebus.windows.net/";

  /// <summary>
  /// The get shared access signature token.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="sasKeyName">
  /// The shared access signature key name.
  /// </param>
  /// <param name="sasKeyValue">
  /// The shared access signature key value.
  /// </param>
  /// <returns>
  /// The <see cref="string"/>.
  /// </returns>
  public static string GetSasToken(string sasKeyName, string sasKeyValue)
  {
      var expiry = GetExpiry();
      var stringToSign = WebUtility.UrlEncode(BaseServiceBusAddress ) + "\n" + expiry;

      var algorithm = WinRTCrypto.MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(MacAlgorithm.HmacSha256);
      var hasher = algorithm.CreateHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sasKeyValue));
      hasher.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign));
      var mac = hasher.GetValueAndReset();
      var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(mac);

      var sasToken = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}", WebUtility.UrlEncode(baseAddress), WebUtility.UrlEncode(signature), expiry, sasKeyName);
      return sasToken;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Posts an order data transfer object to queue.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="orderDto">
  /// The order data transfer object.
  /// </param>
  /// <param name="serviceBusNamespace">
  /// The service bus namespace.
  /// </param>
  /// <param name="sasKeyName">
  /// The shared access signature key name.
  /// </param>
  /// <param name="sasKey">
  /// The shared access signature key.
  /// </param>
  /// <param name="queue">
  /// The queue.
  /// </param>
  /// <returns>
  /// The <see cref="Task"/>.
  /// </returns>
  public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostOrderDtoToQueue(OrderDto orderDto, string serviceBusNamespace, string sasKeyName, string sasKey, string queue)
  {
      using (var client = new HttpClient())
      {
          client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseServiceBusAddress);
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

          var token = GetSasToken(sasKeyName, sasKey);
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", token);

          HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(orderDto), Encoding.UTF8);
          content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

          var path = BaseServiceBusAddress + queue + "/messages";

          return await client.PostAsync(path, content);
      }
  }

  /// <summary>
  ///     Gets the expiry for a shared access signature token
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns>
  ///     The <see cref="string" /> expiry.
  /// </returns>
  private static string GetExpiry()
  {
      var sinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
      return Convert.ToString((int)sinceEpoch.TotalSeconds + 3600);
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: Hi, can you please share your imports/usings?

Comment: @masoodelsad: using Newtonsoft.Json;
using PCLCrypto;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;